# How to use functional component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and i am using Nextjs framework, Right now i am tyring to fetch data from database using nextjs, But right now i am getting following error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined,How can i remove this ? Here is my current code

```
import { Box, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
}

function Test({products}) {
    return (
      <Box>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Box>
            <Text> {product.title} </Text>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
    );
  }

export default Test;
```

Here is my index.js file

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Test from '../components/testing/test'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Test/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You are not accessing `id` property in your code, where does the error come from?

Comment: The error posted w.r.t. code attached has no relation .... pls include the code where the error occurred

Comment: you are returning products in the first function without defining it ... and of course where is the id property in your code?

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri: what is the solution sir ? can you update my code so i can check and implement at my side

Comment: @priynaka that code is not enough to test the problem you need to add the code whre you access the id property ... and i think you mean to write const products = await response.json() **instead of** const data = await response.json()

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri i did sir but still getting same error

Comment: thats why you need to show us the code thats causing the problem (the code where are you using the id)

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri i already mention my code ( component) , kindly explain that which type of code you want to see ?

Comment: @priynaka i'll try reproducing the error in my local envirement then respond to you ... **but** i need you to give me the structure of the data response from the server ... is it { products :[ {id:1 , title:"title"} ...]}

Comment: @priynaka i answered below try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look i think i know where the problem is :

the first problem is that you are using the getStaticProps function in a components while it can only be used in a page (the files inside the pages/ folder) so we need first to move it to index.js like this

**index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Test from '../components/testing/test'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  const products= await response.json(); //<- i changed this becaus it was wrong

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
}

export default function Home({products}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Test products={products}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**test.js**

```
import { Box, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function Test({products}) {
    return (
      <Box>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Box key={product.id}>
            <Text> {product.title} </Text>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
    );
  }

export default Test;
```

**the code above worked for me as it is 'except that my link is different of course'**

the second problem is that you were getting your data in the data variable

```
const data = await response.json();
```

while returning products variable which is undefined

```
  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
```

i changed it in your code so it became

```
  const products= await response.json(); //<- i changed this becaus it was wrong

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
```

now that should work (it worked in my local envirements)

**Notes**

i added a key in your map function

```
          <Box>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <Box key={product.id}>
                <Text> {product.title} </Text>
              </Box>
            ))}
          </Box>
```

so it don't give you a warning  but thats only possible if your product have an id property so if it gave you an error about id property just remove it.

second notes is that my products is structured like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "12346",
    "title": " test"
  },
  {
    "id": "154346",
    "title": " just"
  },
  {
    "id": "169346",
    "title": " another"
  },
  {
    "id": "154326",
    "title": " example"
  }
]
```

so if your structur is different it may cause problems

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should pass key value in map function like key={products.id},
and in the next step check part of code

return {
props: {
products,
},
};

do you want to pass products as props or data as props?

and check whether API link https://fakestoreapi.com/products is correct?
in the last step, check response in console.log().

Comment: You cannot answer a question with more questions.  This does not solve the problem.